# rake jasmine:headless rake aborted, yet all specs pass

Tags: jasmine

Only things that I can think of is this output here:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'text' [null] is not an object.
```

Here is the full output:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'text' [null] is not an object.
..
PASS: 2 tests, 0 failures, 0.004 secs.

Test ordering seed: --seed 7079
rake aborted!
Jasmine::Headless::TestFailure

Tasks: TOP => jasmine:headless
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I understand this should not be a console.log issue, but to be safe, I removed EVERY SINGLE reference to console.log in all js / coffeee script files.  grepped for it, and it's gone in the application.  Cleared out the files in /tmp/cache/assets/ and still I get this TypeError, thought all specs pass.  Really putting a damper on continuous integration.

Running a stack trace simply shows that the error occurs because the result of Jasmine::Headless::Runner is the value 1...

Anyone run across this issue / find a fix?

On the flip side, if anyone knows how to force Jasmine to report the TypeError as an error, I'll take that too.  Just looking for some consistency in what is reported and what the status of my builds will be...

Comment: In meantime, I finally got the runner.html file outputting and this made finding the error very simple :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did to find the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My disgusting hack to get error code correct:

```
bundle exec jasmine-headless-webkit | sed "s/\e\[\d+m//g" > ./jasmine.txt
passing=`cat ~/jobs/jasmine/workspace/jasmine.txt | grep "PASS:"`
echo passing=$passing
```